# What are other potentials like the Henon-Heiles Potential?

Tags: potential, astrophysics, galaxies

The Henon-Heiles Potential, as I have learned, is a two-dimensional nonlinear axi-symmetric potential of galactic systems. I wanted to know if there are any other potentials that also describe astronomical structures. However when I tried searching this up on google but it thought that I wanted to know what potential energy means.

So are there other potentials like the Henon-Heiles Potential?